# Missing Registered apps section on google developers console

Tags: google-app-engine, google-plus

The documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#creatingdeletingprojects) talks about **Registered apps** section as shown in the image below:
[image]

However I couldn't fine any thing related with that. Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Does anyone knows where exactly I can find **Registered apps** section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are actually looking for is the "create new Client Id" under Credentials. The detailed view of that has you specify the type of application the credentials will be used for.

[image]

Comment: I was actually searching where exactly "Registered apps" is written as mentioned in the docs. Anyways, is it mandatory to mention `outh2callback` in the `AUTHORIZED REDIRECT URI` section? Can't both the links be exactly similar?

Comment: I put my answer because I believe "registered apps" no longer exist and has been replaced by the "credentials" page. Redirect URIs require a paths match between your configuration and actual use. It doesn't have to be `/oauth2callback` but if you use `/callback/google` or anything else that needs to be there.

Comment: I see. Can both the URL's in `AUTHORIZED JAVASCRIPT ORIGINS` and `AUTHORIZED REDIRECT URI` be same or one needs to be different as shown in the example image above?

Comment: You can use as many or as few domains that are the same or different depending on your needs. They origins can not have paths, redirect URI needs to have paths.

Comment: AUTHORIZED JAVASCRIPT ORIGINS and AUTHORIZED REDIRECT URI can be the same, but keep in mind that when a user grants authorization, he'll be redirected to the REDIRECT URI with ?code=authorization_code appended to the REDIRECT URI. Having a handler for REDIRECT URI looks cleaner IMHO.